# Magento - How do I require a phone number only for certain products?

Tags: magento

I only want to require users to enter a phone number on certain higher-end products. 90% of purchases don't require the user to enter a phone number. How can I make the field only appear and be required in the checkout process when the cart contains products with a certain attribute set to "yes"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use custom options of products

which is available in products

Go to product at the bottom of product you will see custom options.

**Add New Option**

Please see below snapshot

[image]

Comment: Doesn't that add the field to the product page?  I want the field to be in the regular checkout process.

Comment: it doesnot add field to checkout but you can add programmatically it will show on checkout as well